# Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates. No packages exist

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I'm trying to create a new Blazor App. But I can't install / find the template for *Blazor WebAssembly*. I have tried

```
dotnet new --install "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates"
```

I have installed: `dotnet-sdk-3.1.102-win-x64`. But I get the following:

```
C:\Users\jon\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v3.1.102\scratch\restore.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates. No packages exist with this id in source(s): C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder, Telerik Blazor
  Restore failed in 221.08 ms for C:\Users\jon\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v3.1.102\scratch\restore.csproj
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.2.0-preview1.20073.1
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/get-started?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio